# Is there a way to declare a member in a way that will make it static in all derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I have several abstract classes that need to manage static vectors containing pointers to every instance of themselves. Here's a simplified example of how one of those classes looks:

```
class AbstractBase1
{
public:
    AbstractBase1()
    {
        allInstances_.push_back(this);
    }
    AbstractBase1(const AbstractBase1& source)
      : AbstractBase1()
    {
        //Copy data from source
    }
    AbstractBase1(const AbstractBase1&& source)
      : AbstractBase1()
    {
        //Copy data from source
    }
    virtual ~AbstractBase1()
    {
        //Find the index of 'this' with std::find and remove it from allInstances_
    }
    virtual void purelyVirtualMethod() = 0;
    static void doSomethingWithAllInstances()
    {
        for (AbstractBase1* ptr : allInstances_)
        {
            ptr->purelyVirtualMethod();
        }
    }
private:
    static std::vector<AbstractBase1*> allInstances_;
    //Some data that will be inherited
};
```

So rather than having to write all that code for every class that needs this functionality, I figured I would create an InstanceTracker class containing this functionality, and then have all those classes inherit from it.
But I can't wrap my head around how this InstanceTracker class would look, since I don't want this class to manage a static vector of all its derived classes' instances. What I want is that each class that inherits from InstanceTracker will get their own static vector that will manage its instances.

Is there a way to achieve this or will I just have to write the instance-tracking code for every class that needs it?

Comment: If the abstract class `A` has derived classes `B` and `C`, does `A` "manage" both vectors? Or are they known only to `B` and `C`?

Comment: Whatever it is that you are trying to do, don't.

Comment: @aschepler No, the goal is that B and C would manage their own vectors. Again, I understand that this might not be possible, if it's not I will just continue typing the instance-tracking code for every class that needs it.

Comment: In that case, perhaps a mix-in CRTP class could help.

Comment: @aschepler Never heard of that, could you explain what a CRTP class is? Maybe post as an answer with a code example? Would be really helpful

Comment: On another read, I'm not sure I get the goal. The various derived classes which manage the vectors are abstract, meaning there are classes further derived from them? Editing in a sample of "the long way" and maybe a not-working attempt at a shorter way could help.

Comment: @JensB CRTP means that class `A` would inherit from `InstanceTracker<A>`, whereas class `B` would inherit from `InstanceTracker<B>`. Definetely the pattern to go here.

Comment: @aschepler Added some example code to my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use template:

```
template <typename Tag>
class AbstractBaseT
{
public:
    AbstractBaseT() { allInstances_.push_back(this); }
    AbstractBaseT(const AbstractBase1& source) : AbstractBaseT()
    {
        //Copy data from source
    }
    AbstractBaseT(AbstractBaseT&& source) : AbstractBase1()
    {
        //Move data from source
    }
    virtual ~AbstractBaseT()
    {
        //Find the index of 'this' with std::find and remove it from allInstances_
    }
    virtual void purelyVirtualMethod() = 0;
    static void doSomethingWithAllInstances()
    {
        for (AbstractBase1* ptr : allInstances_)
        {
            ptr->purelyVirtualMethod();
        }
    }
private:
    static std::vector<AbstractBaseT*> allInstances_;
    //Some data that will be inherited
};
```

and then

```
using AbstractBase1 = AbstractBaseT<struct tag1>;
```

or the CRTP way might also be useful:

```
struct AbstractBase2 : AbstractBaseT<AbstractBase2>
{
    // ...
};
```